# Alternando de 16 para 64 bits durante o boot de um Intel PC compatible

Tags: sistema-operacional, assembly, intel, x86, x64

Há algum tempo estudei para criar um rascunho de sistema operacional para computadores Intel PC compatible, que na verdade não precisava fazer muita coisa, além de colocar o computador em modo 32 bits, tratar as interrupções de teclado, e (na época) das portas seriais.

Meu procedimento na época era esse (funcionava muito bem):

```
    cli
    cld

    ;habilita o gate A20, liberando acesso a mais de 1MB
_A20_1:
    in al, 064h
    test al, 2
    jnz _A20_1
    mov al, 0D1h
    out 064h, al
_A20_2:
    in al, 064h
    test al, 2
    jnz _A20_2
    mov al, 0DFh
    out 060h, al

    ;calcula e preenche a IDT e a GDT
    ;...

    db 066h
    lgdt [GDT]
    db 066h
    lidt [IDT]

    ;liga o bit do modo protegido
    smsw ax
    or ax,1
    lmsw ax

    ;jmp next
    ;next:
    db 0ebh
    db 000h
    ;entra em modo 32 bits
    ;PCODE_ADDR contém o endereço do label _32BIT
    ;jmp fword ptr PCODE_ADDR
    db 066h
    db 0ffh
    db 02eh
    dw PCODE_ADDR

_32BIT:
    ;daqui em diante tudo está em 32 bits
    ;...

PCODE_ADDR:
    dd _32BIT ;endereço linear usado para o JUMP
    dw 08h ;seletor usado para o JUMP
```

Minha pergunta é: como eu faço um procedimento similar, mas para colocar o computador em modo 64 bits, partindo do modo 16 bits?

Sei que o Linux é open source, mas o código é grande, e não tenho muita experiência com ele. Se a reposta envolver o código fonte do Linux, eu pediria, por favor, para indicar a versão, o arquivo e as linhas correspondentes.

Comment: Quem sabe você poderá até fazer um sistema operacional, que não seja com licença GNU. Seria uma boa idéia.

Comment: A ideia original nem era criar um sistema operacional verdadeiro, era apenas para fins de aprendizado / didáticos. Mas, quem sabe o que o futuro aguarda ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entrar em Long Mode não é tão simples, eu sugiro começar com estas páginas:

Introdução:
http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64

Modo tradicional:
[http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Stephanvanschaik/Setting_Up_Long_Mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/User%3aStephanvanschaik/Setting_Up_Long_Mode)

Modo direto:
http://wiki.osdev.org/Entering_Long_Mode_Directly

Comment: Não conhecia ese wiki! Legal demais!!! Os dois links finais são exatamente o que eu procurava! :D